# How to get data back from emberjs controller

Tags: ember.js, ember.js-view

I have a list of routes

```
App.Router.map ()->
@resource 'about'

@resource 'users', ->
    @resource 'repositories', path: '/:user_name/repositories'
    @route 'show', path: '/:user_name'
```

In my users show template i also have a view

```
{{#view App.RepositoriesView login=login}}
  <div class="show_repos_control">
      <span>Show Repos</span>
  </div>

  {{#if reposWasQuery}}
    {{#each repositories}}
      {{repo_name}}
    {{/each}}
  {{/if}}   
{{/view}}
```

with view class

```
App.RepositoriesView = Ember.View.extend({
  click: function(evt) {
    this.get('controller').send('showRepos', this.get('login'));
  }
});
```

view class code process into UsersShowController with code

```
App.UsersShowController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  reposWasQuery: false,
  actions:{
      showRepos: function(userName){
          this.set('reposWasQuery', true);
          this.set('repositories', jQuery.getJSON('/users/' + userName + '/repositories'));
    }
  }
})
```

Repository's data assigns as excpected, but in my view i can't dispay it. Getting error "#error some number"

Comment: what's the deal with the two return statements in your `App.Router.map()` function?  You don't need any `return` statements in your `map()`.

Comment: If I were to guess I'd say it was a coffeescript to js, it kind of looks like it.

Comment: It might be usefull the post the complete error... The double return statements are very weird indeed.

Comment: i use coffeescript for my routes, this dirty code generate js2coffee fir me, sorry, i will update into coffee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very strange to render a `view` for a controller and route with an open close block.

using `{{render 'repositories' myRepositoriesArray}}` instead will do the following:

1. Render a new `Repositories` controller with the `myRepositoriesArray` as your data.
2. Implicitly create a `RepositoriesView`.

You would need to put this code:

```
  <div class="show_repos_control">
      <span>Show Repos</span>
  </div>

  {{#if reposWasQuery}}
    {{#each repositories}}
      {{repo_name}}
    {{/each}}
  {{/if}}
```

In the `repositories` template.

Ember is build with convention over configuration in mind. You should read up on the `render` helper and the things ember expects or create for you when rendering a route.

Comment: It works well when in my RepositoriesController repositories assigns fixture data, for example `[{name: "repo 1}, {name: "repo 2"}]`, but if i use `jQuery.getJSON("https://api.github.com/users/olefine/repos")`. i get error `Uncaught #<error> `